# Solid wood front door seasonal swelling makes latching deadbolt difficult

Tags: doors

My front door is solid wood and in the summer it swells making it difficult to latch the deadbolt (I have to lean my weight into the door to latch from the inside or pull on the handle from the outside to latch it).

In the winter the door latches without issue. If anything it feels "loose" in the latch during the winter.

I'd like to modify the door or the frame/jamb to make it easier to latch the deadbolt.

What do I need to do to determine what the specific issue with the door is and how can I modify the door to easy to latch in all seasons.

Answer (score 1):

The trim sounds like it is a bit snug, when I lived back east I had a similar problem . I adjusted the trim then found in winter it had leaks, I used weather stripping to solve the problem, I had it where it did not stick in summer and a tack strip of weather stripping that sealed to the door in winter worked great, I only lived there for 3 years so I don’t know how well it held up after that but while we were there from the sub 0 temps in winter to the +100 with 100% humidity the door was easy to open and close with both locks.